# insert arabic data from java to mysql on macOS shows?

Tags: java, mysql, arabic

i developed a small program to store some data in Arabic.

when i use the program on any windows system the program is perfect and nothing wrong while inserting and retrieving the data.

but when i use the program on mac-OS, the program works fine while retrieving the old Arabic records stored into MySQL database, but

when i insert a new data in Arabic it appears like ???????? ????? in MySQL database .

can anyone help me to understand whats is the wrong with that?

Comment: Are you accessing the same database? What is the encoding of your database? (It should be something-utf8.) What it that program you use, in what language is it written?

Comment: im using java and MySQL as shown on the subject

Comment: and yes im accessing the same database and the encoding is utf8 .

Comment: on windows everything perfect but on macOS it shows ?????

Comment: When you start your program, what is the value of `LANG` variable? Open a shell and check what `env | grep LANG` says. Locate the shell script that starts the Java program, and add `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` before the `java ...` line. See if it helps.